# WP REST API posts feed doesn't show the featured image

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I'm trying to feed some posts from my wordpress blog into my PHP website using the WP REST API v2 plugin.  My code is:

```
  <?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('http://noticias.uscs.edu.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=6&filter[orderby]=date');
    // Convert the JSON to an array of posts
    $posts = json_decode($json);

    foreach ($posts as $p) {
      echo '<p><a href="'.$p->link.'">'.$p->title->rendered.'</a><p>';
      // Output the featured image (if there is one)
      echo $p->featured_image ? '<img src="' . $p->featured_image->guid . '">' : '';

    }

  ?>
```

The [`$json` response](http://noticias.uscs.edu.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=6&filter[orderby]=date) is:

```
[{"code":"json_no_route","message":"Nenhuma rota foi encontrada que corresponde com a URL e o m\u00e9todo de requisi\u00e7\u00e3o"}]
```

Almost everything is right, less the featured image that isn't shown.  What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress new update (4.4) add the rest api in the core:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/28/rest-api-welcome-the-infrastructure-to-core/

You can get the thumbmail using the Posts API
http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/